# Как преобразовать перечисление в строку или число?

Tags: delphi

Как перевести свой тип данных в String или Integer?

```
type
  Phone = (buttons, numerous, sensor);

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  MyPhone: Phone;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyPhone := sensor;
  label1.Caption := MyPhone;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, давно не сидел за Delphi, но, кажется, так:

- в integer: `label1.Caption:=integer(MyPhone);`
- в string:  `label1.Caption:=IntToStr(integer(MyPhone));`

Comment: Доброе напутствие. Имена типов в Delphi принято начинать с заглавной Т, а перед элементами перечисляемого типа данных добавлять строчными буквами префикс в виде сокращенного названия описываемого типа. В вашем случае это могло бы выглядеть так:
type
  TPhone = (phButtons, phNumerous, phSensor);

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас тут насоветуют... )

Итак, вам нужно привести не "свой тип данных", а перечисляемый тип Phone к целочисленному или строке.

Для первого в Delphi предусмотрена функция `ord`:

```
var i: integer;
    MyPhone: Phone;   
begin
  MyPhone := sensor;
  i := ord(numerous);
  ....
end;
```

Со вторым чуть сложнее. Штатно (как например, в Java) преобразовать перечисляемый тип в строку не получится. Но можно воспользоваться RTTI, и, подключив модуль `TypInfo`, все же выцепить искомое:

```
uses TypInfo;
...
var MyPhone: Phone;
    s : string;
begin
  MyPhone := sensor;
  s := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(Phone), ord(MyPhone));
  ....
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите сериализовать объект, то это можно сделать на основе RTTI. Используя функцию

```
function GetPropList(TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; out APropList: PPropList): integer;
```

получить список свойств и пройтись по ним в цикле, интересующие - записать.

```
var
    i: integer;
    info: PPropInfo;
    count: integer;
    list: PPropList;
begin
    count := GetPropList(PTypeInfo(AObject.ClassInfo), list);
    for i := 0 to count - 1 do
    begin
        info := list^[i];
        // Обработать свойство
    end;
end;
```